# C# get sql table column value and put it in a variable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a user login menu. I want to redirect the user based on their Level. The Level data is in the SQL table. I want to get the Level data from the table based on their username and assign it to a variable.

```
protected void btnDefault_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//filter entered text
string strUserName = Tools.checkSQLInjection(txtUserName.Text).Trim();
string strPassword = Tools.checkSQLInjection(txtPassword.Text);
string strError = "";

//Get Dealer Level Value
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dealerLvl FROM Users where email='" + strUserName + "'");
string strDealerLvl = "dealerLvl".ToString();
int intDealerLvl;
bool isParsable = Int32.TryParse(strDealerLvl, out intDealerLvl);

if (strDealerLvl == "1")
  {  Response.Redirect("/dealers/dashboard"); }
else if (strDealerLvl == "2")
  {  Response.Redirect("/dealers/dashboard-2"); }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: Yeah, until you remove the sql injection vulnerability, few people will be able to help you because no good answer will include that code above.

Comment: Don't rely on home made sql injection prevention tools. Parameterized queries are a proven system to avoid sql injection. (and your code will be more clear, less prone to syntax errors and could be optimized by the sql engine)

Comment: However, it seems that you need to read some tutorial on how to create a select command, **execute** it and read the results. For example: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ado-net-sqlcommand-class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be checking the password, but perhaps that supposed to come later.

A working code stub to do this would look like say this:

```
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
int intDealerLvl = 0;

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT dealerLv1 FROM Users where email = @meail", 
          new SqlConnection(My.Settings.test3ConnectionString)))
{
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strUserName;
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
}

if (MyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    intDealerLvl = MyTable.Rows(0)(0);

switch (intDealerLvl)
{
    case 1:
        {
            Response.Redirect("/dealers/dashboard");
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            Response.Redirect("/dealers/dashboard-2"); 
            break;
        }

    default:
        {
            // no level found - where to go??
            break;
        }
}
```

However, it not clear if you supposed to be checking the password, and if so then of course we use this:

```
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
string strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT dealerLv1 FROM Users where email = @Email and Password = @Pass";

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, 
          new SqlConnection(My.Settings.test3ConnectionString)))
{
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strUserName;
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strPassword;
cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

if (MyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    intDealerLvl = MyTable.Rows(0)(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it working. Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dealerLvl FROM Users where email= @strUserName", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strUserName", strUserName);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    da.Fill(ds);
        
                //Get the result of the first row        
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        
               //Get the value of the column in the first row        
               string strDealerLvl = dr["dealerLvl"].ToString();    
            }
```

Comment: Parameterize your queries, and dispose objects with `using`

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for that I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Appreciate it, I got it to work.